# javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb, eclipselink

I am trying to delete the data record of a particular candidate...locally it is working..but when I am deploying it in USA server ..it is showing error...

```
[#|2014-10-10T06:51:31.089-0400|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=56;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB RequestHandler method public java.lang.String com.webservices.RequestHandler.deleteSupply(java.lang.String)
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2204)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2004)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1906)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:198)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
    at $Proxy206.removeCE(Unknown Source)
    at com.logic.__EJB31_Generated__SupplyManager__Intf____Bean__.removeCE(Unknown Source)
    at com.webservices.RequestHandler.deleteSupply(RequestHandler.java:744)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:5243)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:615)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:567)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doAround(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor181.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:858)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:797)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:367)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5215)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5203)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:190)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:84)
    at $Proxy191.deleteSupply(Unknown Source)
    at com.webservices.__EJB31_Generated__RequestHandler__Intf____Bean__.deleteSupply(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:156)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:208)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:115)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:115)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:67)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:740)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:731)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:452)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:633)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.utility.SessionCheckFilter.doFilter(SessionCheckFilter.java:33)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:4926)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4761)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1955)
```

I am totally new to these concepts and don't know what the problem is..! if the error is there then it should show in eclipse while debugging..but in my localhost is is working fine but not when I am deploying the war file of this project in USA server...

Comment: Your bean is throwing an exception causing the transaction to be rolled back.  You will need to look at the application code and possibly add debugging to log the reason why if its not showing in the log already.

Comment: the problem is that my code shows no error... i have debugged it and it is deleting the candidate also but after deploying it is showing the error in server log... @Chris

Comment: Is this the entire exception trace? containers normally have a chain of caused by, before you can actually see the error

Comment: @maress no..i have just copied the part which i think was the reason ..do you want me to paste the whole log ?

Answer (score 2):

In EJB if any of the method which is continuing a Transaction if throws a RunTimeException (like NPE) then it cause the transaction to Roll Back and in Trace you will be shown TransactionRollBackException.

If you will check your log in detail in the exception trace you will find a Caused by tag where your actual exception will be printed.

Resolve that Exception as per your code and this will work fine.